# Not getting counter metric after unregister and register again in prometheous

Tags: go, prometheus

I need to implement counter metrices on conditional basis. While implementing the counters facing issue when the condition changes. like

**Pseudo Code:**

```
counter =prometheus.NewCounter(prometheus.CounterOpts{
    Name: "success_count",
    Help: "The number of API count success. ",
})
// On Init
defaultRegistry := prometheus.NewRegistry()
prometheus.DefaultRegisterer = defaultRegistry
prometheus.DefaultGatherer = defaultRegistry

prometheus.MustRegister(service.ProtectSuccessCount)

if disableMetricTrue{
    prometheus.Unregister(counter)
else
    prometheus.MustRegister(counter)
```

On DisableMetrics -> working fine
While EnableMetrics After disable, I am getting only below data. custom metric counter not showing.

```
# HELP promhttp_metric_handler_requests_in_flight Current number of scrapes being served.
# TYPE promhttp_metric_handler_requests_in_flight gauge 
promhttp_metric_handler_requests_in_flight 1
# HELP promhttp_metric_handler_requests_total Total number of scrapes by HTTP status 
code.
# TYPE promhttp_metric_handler_requests_total counter 
promhttp_metric_handler_requests_total{code="200"} 7 
promhttp_metric_handler_requests_total{code="500"} 0 
promhttp_metric_handler_requests_total{code="503"} 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a [Collector](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus#Collector) implementation that conditionally emits the metric:

```
var counter = prometheus.NewCounter(prometheus.CounterOpts{
    Name: "success_count",
    Help: "The number of API count success. ",
})

func main() {
    prometheus.MustRegister(counterExporter{})
}

type counterExporter struct{}

func (e counterExporter) Describe(ch chan<- *prometheus.Desc) {
    ch <- counter.Desc()
}

func (e counterExporter) Collect(ch chan<- prometheus.Metric) {
    if !disableMetricTrue {
        ch <- counter
    }
}
```